# What difference does it make if the turns in a tesla coil overlap?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, experimental-technique

Would a tesla coil in which the primary coil is made by overlapping the turns of the wire work?

Comment: As long as you satisfy the resonance conditions for the coils and you manage to keep the Q high, pretty much every configuration will "work" to some extent, but the optimum Q for coils is geometry dependent, so do your homework before you start building "any" geometry. You also need to understand why light coupling leads to better results than strong coupling. Develop strategies to measure the Q of your coils with a low voltage setup, so you are not completely in the dark with what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is actually a part of my research.

Comment: Good luck and long sparks! :-)